# C++ SDL What does the | do?

Tags: c++

```
screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(1000,1000,32, SDL_HWSURFACE | SDL_FULLSCREEN);
```

What does the `|` do in `SDL_HWSURFACE | SDL_FULLSCREEN`? (I tried googling this but google wont accept special characters..)

Comment: It's used to combine flags in whichever way you choose. Each one most likely represents a different bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answers have explained it's a bitwise OR, but you probably want to know how that works:

The flags are passed as a binary number, like 00001000 or 01000000, and each bit represents an individual flag. So the first bit (0) means HW_SURFACE is off, and the second bit (1) means FULLSCREEN is on. (Note that these are examples, I'm not sure about the actual bits.)

So what the bitwise OR function does is combine those two flags by comparing each bit and saying "Is this bit OR this bit 1?" and if either is 1, it will set the result to 1. This will provide the result 01001000 which can be parsed by SDL to set the appropriate flags.

Comment: Brilliant answer, you kept it understandable for me and short :)

Answer (score 7):

C / C++ APIs often set up bit 'flags' when there are a lot of different, non-mutually exclusive options that can be set for a given function call.  Each of the flags will be assigned a bit position in a value (often a `DWORD` or other large integer type).  One or more of these bits can then be set by bitwise OR-ing a collection of defined constants that represent the options and give you a more clear label to identify them than a raw numeric constant.  The resultant value is passed as a single argument to the API function, which helps to keep the signature manageable.

In this particular case, `SDL_HWSURFACE` and `SDL_FULLSCREEN` represent options that can be passed in to the `SDL_SetVideoMode` call.  There are probably several other possible options available as well that were not set in this case.  This particular call sets the two options by bitwise OR-ing the flag constants together, and passing the result as the last parameter.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time explaining this. It's about time that I learn more about bitwise operations, because I dont fully understand this yet.

Comment: So let me get this straight: SDL_HWSURFACE and SDL_FULLSCREEN both hold values, and when a bitwise OR operation is used on them it returns a value. And I'm guessing that value is unique so inside the function SDL_SetVideoMode() theres a switch case that checks for the value that comes through the 4th parameter so it knows what to do?

Comment: @user1534664 There are 8 bits in a byte. Let's say the value we are working with is a byte. This is a contrived example: `SDL_HWSURFACE` will set the first 4 bits 'ON', and `SDL_FULLSCREEN` will set the last 4 bits ON. Notice how they have their own dedicated bits. If the first 4 bits are OFF, then we know `SDL_HWSURFACE` isn't set. If the last 4 bits are OFF, then we know `SDL_FULLSCREEN` isn't set. `SDL_SetVideoMode` checks the first 4 bits and notices those bits are set. That means `SDL_HWSURFACE` was passed to the function.  Then it checks the last 4 bits and sees `SDL_FULLSCREEN`. etc.

Comment: Marlon thanks mate, your explanation was the most easy to understand. If you would've put it in an actual answer instead of a comment on this answer I would've marked yours as the accepted answer =)

Answer (score 5):

That's the `bitwise OR` operator. It applies it to `SDL_HWSURFACE` and `SDL_FULLSCREEN`.

Comment: can you elaborate what a bitwise operation has to do with SDL_HWSURFACE and SDL_FULLSCREEN?

Comment: @user1534664: Googling the term "bitwise or" gives a lot of results, like for example http://www.vipan.com/htdocs/bitwisehelp.html, which explains bit masks and how the bitwise operators can be used to manipulate them

Comment: Yeah I was already searching it up but on a first impression it seemed awkward :)

Answer (score 1):

The `|` operator means bitwise or. That means each bit in the result is set if the corresponding bit in the left hand or the right hand value is set. So `1 | 2 = 3`, because 1 in binary is 01 and 2 in binary is 10. So the result in binary is 11 which is 3 in decimal.

In your example this is used to pass a lot of different on/off options to a function. Each of the constants has exactly one bit set. The function then looks at the value you pass and using the bitwise and operator `&` to check which ones you specified.

Comment: So basically it does an bitwise OR on SDL_HWSURFACE and SDL_FULLSCREEN? But that makes me wonder, what values do they hold? And doesn't it return a value afterwards?